# How to reverse an integer in haskell?

Tags: haskell, integer, int

I need help on how to reverse a `Integer` in Haskell with the following type signature:

```
reverseInt :: Integer -> Integer
reverseInt a = undefined -- help here
```

I need the `Integer` input number to be reversed like the example below.

**Example:**

```
> reverseInt 1989
9891
```

Comment: This is not "reversing an integer", in any canonical mathematical sense! It's _reversing the decimal representation_, which is in itself a pretty much completely useless operation. You probably shouldn't do this on integers at all, but rather reverse the `show`n integer-string only in the place where you need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the number to a string, revert that, then convert the reversed string back to a number. `Integer` values can be negative, so take care of a leading `-`:

```
reverseInt :: Integer -> Integer
reverseInt x | x < 0     = 0 - (read . reverse . tail . show $ x)
             | otherwise = read . reverse . show $ x
```

Comment: Consider doing it mathematically too, reducing it to a list of integers and then reversing that.

Comment: @Tetigi Any program is math.

Answer (score 13):

```
reverseInt :: Integer -> Integer
reverseInt = read . reverse . show
```

This does not address negative numbers. If you need to reverse negative numbers, you can simply use

```
reverseInt :: Integer -> Integer
reverseInt x = (*) (signum x) . read . reverse . show . abs  $ x
```

Comment: @EarlGray: Okay, that's a _real_ coincidence, I just edited that into my answer :D, although I like the functional use of `(*)` a little bit more.

Answer (score 11):

One way to avoid the use of `show` is this one

```
reverseInt :: Integer -> Integer
reverseInt n = aux (n,0)
             where aux (0,y) = y
                   aux (x,y) = let (x',y') = x `quotRem` 10
                               in aux (x',10*y+y')
```

and it works with negative numbers too.

### EDIT2:

As pointed out in the comments the aux function can be a bit optimized omitting the tuple, which can prevent the compiler from evaluating to whnf (weak head normal form), i.e. if the compiler sees an expression it evaluates it as little as necessary, until it sees the first constructor. And in case of aux it is the tuple constructor `(,)`. A good feeling for whnf can be achieved with ghci + `:sprint`, see simon marlow's book (http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html).

```
reverseInt :: Int -> Int
reverseInt n = aux n 0
             where aux 0 y = y
                   aux x y = let (x',y') = x `quotRem` 10
                             in aux x' (10*y+y')
```

As pointed out by @FrerichRaabe this does the required task, but understanding it is a bit more tricky than - `read . reverse . show`, I admit that. So I'll explain in an example what `aux` does:

```
aux 1234 0 => 1234 `quotRem` 10 => (123,4) => x'= 123, y'= 4
           => aux 123 (0*10+4)  => aux 123 4
aux 123 4  => 123 `quotRem` 10  => (12,3)  => x'= 12, y'= 3
           => aux 12 (4*10+3)   => aux 12 43
aux 12 43  => 12 `quotRem` 10   => (1,2)   => x'= 1, y'= 2
           => aux 1 (43*10+2)   => aux 1 432
aux 1 432  => 1 `quotRem` 10    => (0,1)   => x'= 0, y'= 1
           => aux 0 (432*10+1)  => aux 0 4321
aux 0 4321 => 4321
```

### EDIT:

I decided whether my assumptions of including `show` is a bad idea were justified.

**short version** yes!

**long version**
I put all versions in one file and added a strict version of my approach to see, if the non strict part in the accumulator mattered (as it turned out: not really). What mattered was the choice between `Int` (which is Int64) on my machine and `Integer` in my Versions

- the Int     version took about 200 ns
- Integer version ---- " -----  600 ns

the other versions involving `show` and `read` took a bit longer,
but all of them were around 6000 ns - which is a factor of 30 resp. 10 compared to my version.
For further information you may want to look at the report produced by the `criterion` library (thank you Bryan O'Sullivan!!), save the files below and type in your shell.

```
$ ghc -O --make benchmarks.hs
$ ./benchmarks -o Report.html
```

**RevInt.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module RevInt where

epsilon_fast :: Int-> Int
epsilon_fast n = aux n 0
               where aux :: Int -> Int -> Int
                     aux 0 !y = y
                     aux x !y = let (x',y') = x `quotRem` 10
                                 in aux x' (10*y+y')

epsilon_Integer :: Integer -> Integer
epsilon_Integer n = aux (n,0)
                  where aux (0,y) = y
                        aux (x,y) = let (x',y') = x `quotRem` 10
                                    in aux (x',10*y+y')

epsilon_rInt :: Int-> Int
epsilon_rInt n = aux (n,0)
               where aux (0,y) = y
                     aux (x,y) = let (x',y') = x `quotRem` 10
                                 in aux (x',10*y+y')

epsilon_Integer' :: Integer -> Integer
epsilon_Integer' n = aux (n,0)
                   where aux (0,y) = y
                         aux (x,y) = let (x',y') = x `quotRem` 10
                                         !z = 10*y+y'
                                     in aux (x',z)

epsilon_rInt' :: Int-> Int
epsilon_rInt' n = aux (n,0)
                where aux (0,y) = y
                      aux (x,y) = let (x',y') = x `quotRem` 10
                                      !z = 10*y+y'
                                  in aux (x',z)

fRaabe_Integer :: Integer -> Integer
fRaabe_Integer x | x < 0     = 0 - (read . reverse . tail . show $ x)
                 | otherwise = read . reverse . show $ x

fRaabe_Int :: Int -> Int
fRaabe_Int x | x < 0     = 0 - (read . reverse . tail . show $ x)
             | otherwise = read . reverse . show $ x

zeta_Int :: Int -> Int
zeta_Int x = (*) (signum x) . read . reverse . show . abs  $ x

zeta_Integer :: Integer -> Integer
zeta_Integer x = (*) (signum x) . read . reverse . show . abs  $ x
```

**benchmarks.hs**

```
import Criterion.Main
import RevInt

main :: IO ()
main =  defaultMain
           [bgroup "epsilon_fast"    [ bench "123456789" $ whnf epsilon_fast 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf epsilon_fast 987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "epsilon_Integer" [ bench "123456789" $ whnf epsilon_Integer 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf epsilon_Integer  987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "epsilon_rInt"    [ bench "123456789" $ whnf epsilon_rInt 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf epsilon_rInt 987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "epsilon_Integer'"[ bench "123456789" $ whnf epsilon_Integer' 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf epsilon_Integer' 987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "epsilon_rInt'"   [ bench "123456789" $ whnf epsilon_rInt' 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf epsilon_rInt' 987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "fRaabe_Int"      [ bench "123456789" $ whnf fRaabe_Int 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf fRaabe_Int 987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "fRaabe_Integer"  [ bench "123456789" $ whnf fRaabe_Integer 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf fRaabe_Integer 987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "zeta_Int"        [ bench "123456789" $ whnf zeta_Int 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf zeta_Int 987654321 ]
           ,bgroup "zeta_Integer"    [ bench "123456789" $ whnf zeta_Integer 123456789 ,
                                       bench "987654321" $ whnf zeta_Integer 987654321 ]]
```

Comment: This one is nice - I was about to say the same thing! If you were asked how to do this in an interview, this would be the way you should do it :)

Comment: i am about to put a bit of "research" into this and try to compare the above examples and mine - see probably later on for an edit - if my answer is better or worse.

Comment: Why do you write that aux function with a tuple argument? I guess ghc -On will remove it, for some value of n. Nevertheless ... it looks unfamiliar.

Comment: +1 for benchmarking this. I think what's appealing about the `show` based version is that the `show` (and especially `reverse`) nicely communicate what's happening: you are reversing the string representation of an integer. The `quotRem` version is elegant, but just from looking at it it's not too easy to figure out whether what the function does matches the function name.

Comment: @Ingo thanks for pointing that out to me - I was so thinking in tuples because of `quotRem` returning a tuple. @FrerichRaabe yes I should explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Much more simpler one

```
reverseint x = (read (reverse(show(abs(x)))) :: Integer)*signum(x)
```

easier to understand, usually we read inputs with read and now you read a string, convert that string to integer, signum(x) takes care of the sign of the number